# Random disconnects from master node NoNodeAvailableException using Elastic Cloud/Found

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using elastic cloud (former found) with shield and the transport java client. The app communicating with ES runs on heroku. I'm running a stress test on a staging environment with one node

```
{
    "cluster_name": ...,
    "status": "yellow", 
    "timed_out": false,
    "number_of_nodes": 1,
    "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
    "active_primary_shards": 19,
    "active_shards": 19,
    "relocating_shards": 0,
    "initializing_shards": 0,
    "unassigned_shards": 7,
    "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
    "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
    "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0
}
```

A the beginning everything works perfectly. But after some time (3-4 minutes) I begin to get some errors. I've set the log level to trace and these are the errors I've been getting (I've replaced with `...` everything that is irrelevant.

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes were available: [[...][...][...][inet[...]]{logical_availability_zone=..., availability_zone=..., max_local_storage_nodes=1, region=..., master=true}]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$RetryListener.onFailure(TransportClientNodesService.java:242)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy$1.handleException(TransportActionNodeProxy.java:78)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$3.run(TransportService.java:290)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.SendRequestTransportException: [...][inet[...]][indices:data/read/search]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:286)
    at org.elasticsearch.shield.transport.ShieldClientTransportService.sendRequest(ShieldClientTransportService.java:41)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy.execute(TransportActionNodeProxy.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient$1.doWithNode(InternalTransportClient.java:109)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:205)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.search(AbstractClient.java:334)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.search(TransportClient.java:416)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder.doExecute(SearchRequestBuilder.java:1122)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
    ...
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [...][inet[...]] Node not connected
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.nodeChannel(NettyTransport.java:936)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.sendRequest(NettyTransport.java:629)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:276)
    ...
```

These are my properties

```
  settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
      .put("client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval", "5s") //Tried it with 30s, same outcome
      .put("client.transport.ping_timeout", "30s")
      .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
      .put("action.bulk.compress", false)
      .put("shield.transport.ssl", true)
      .put("request.headers.X-Found-Cluster", clusterName)
      .put("shield.user", user + ":" + password)
      .put("transport.ping_schedule", "1s") //Tried with 5s, same outcome
      .build();
```

I've also set for every query I make:

```
max_query_response_size=100000
timeout_seconds=30
```

I'm using `ElasticSearch 1.7.2` and `Shield 1.3.2` with corresponding (same version) clients, `Java 1.8.0_65` on my machine - `Java 1.8.0_40` on the node.

I was getting the same errors without a stress test, but the errors happened very randomly so I wanted to reproduce. That's why I'm running this in a single node.

I spotted another error in my logs

```
2016-03-07 23:35:52,177 DEBUG [elasticsearch[Vermin][transport_client_worker][T#7]{New I/O worker #16}] ssl.SslHandler (NettyInternalESLogger.java:debug(63)) - Swallowing an exception raised while writing non-app data
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:433)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

Hot threads

```
0.0% (111.6micros out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[...][transport_client_timer][T#1]{Hashed wheel timer #1}'
 10/10 snapshots sharing following 5 elements
   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.waitForNextTick(HashedWheelTimer.java:445)
   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:364)
   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After reading this http://blog.trifork.com/2015/04/08/dealing-with-nodenotavailableexceptions-in-elasticsearch/ I came to understand a little better how the whole communication works. I haven't tested this yet, but I believe that the problem lies there. The thing is though, even if I confirm that the problem is closed query connections, how do I handle this? Keep the config as is and just reconnect? Do I disable `keepAlive`? If yes, should I be worrying over something else?

Comment: What does your stress test do?

Comment: Also, do you have a **complete** log file from one day where you had the errors and you performed your stress test?

Comment: @AndreiStefan it saves, deletes and mostly searches. The vast majority of the calls are searches, some bulk saves and some bulk and single deletes. The complete log contains sensitive data and I'm not in liberty to share.

Comment: What I'm trying to establish is if you put too much load on your cluster that it's not able to respond in a timely manner.

Comment: I'm getting the same errors during normal use too. When I'm saying normal, I mean very few requests per minute. During the stress test I'm getting much more of these exceptions which is expected. The thing is, I'm now using Jest and accessing Elastic via the Rest API and everything works great.

Comment: Please post the `GET /_nodes/hot_threads` data too. Should be of help

Comment: @ArchitSaxena Sorry for the tragic delay. I've been preoccupied. I've updated my post.

Comment: Did you go through this: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nonodeavailableexception-with-java-transport-client/37702
I think this link should answer your problem. :)

Comment: In the myriads I've seen these past days, this eluded me. So basically even when using found/shield I must poll the IPs. And it seems this was not documented because everyone uses the rest api. Please provide an answer for this, so I can accept it and award the bounty.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena The bounty has expired. But please post an answer and I will award it nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing this link: 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nonodeavailableexception-with-java-transport-client/37702 by [Konrad Beiske](https://www.linkedin.com/in/konrad-beiske-10480b21)

> your application could be resolving the ip address at boot time. The
>   ELB can change ip's at any point in time. For the best reliability
>   your application should add all ip's of the ELB to the client and
>   periodically check the DNS service for changes.
>
> The connection timeout of our ELB's are 5 minutes.

Following should help you fix it:

> Creating a new TransportClient for every request is not ideal as it
>   will imply a new connection handshake for every request and this will
>   hurt your response time. You could have a pool of TransportClients if
>   you prefer, but it will most likely be an unnecessary overhead as the
>   client is thread safe.
>
> My suggestion is that you create a small singleton service that
>   periodically checks for changes to the DNS service and adds any new
>   ip's to your existing transport client. In theory it could be as naive
>   as just adding all ip's discovered every time it checks as the
>   transport client will discard duplicate addresses and also purges old
>   addresses no longer reachable.

Comment: For some reason I must wait 23 hours before awarding the bounty. I've doubled it btw. This was so hard to find because even the found support was claiming that this was handled by the client automatically.

Comment: Feels undeserved, but not complaining :)
Thanks. Glad i could help